# Cytoscape 3.1 not running on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, cytoscape

I was not able to start Cytoscape 3.1.0 on ubuntu 23.04. Please check the unix.sh script fine below.

Thank you for time and your support.

Alex.

./unix.sh

###### Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Linux

- Target Cytoscape version: 3.9.0
- Your Shell: bash

===== Checking Distribution =====

- Linux Distribution: Ubuntu
- Version: 23.04
- Target Platform: x86_64
- Pass: Distribution = Ubuntu
  Fail: This Ubuntu version is not supported: 23.04
  Supported versions are:
- 14.04
- 14.10
- 15.04
- 15.10
- 16.04
- 16.10
- 17 04
- 17 10
- 18.04
- 18.10
- 20.04
- 21.04

===== Checking Java Version =====

- Pass: Current Java Version = 11.0.19

===== Checking $JAVA_HOME =====

- Pass: JAVA_HOME found: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle

===== Checking Connection to Cytoscape App Store =====

- Checking connection to Cytoscape App Store...

apps.cytoscape.org has address 52.34.133.210
./unix.sh: line 164: curl: command not found

- Result:
  Error: Seems connection to App Store is unstable.

traceroute result:
traceroute to apps.cytoscape.org (52.34.133.210), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  _gateway (10.0.0.1)  7.806 ms  7.787 ms  7.784 ms
2  100.93.8.195 (100.93.8.195)  14.115 ms 100.93.8.194 (100.93.8.194)  18.482 ms  18.779 ms
3  po-309-394-rur202.branford.ct.hartford.comcast.net (68.87.155.233)  23.028 ms  23.025 ms  23.021 ms
4  68.85.106.121 (68.85.106.121)  23.049 ms po-2-rur202.branford.ct.hartford.comcast.net (68.86.230.186)  22.272 ms  23.008 ms
5  68.85.106.121 (68.85.106.121)  22.922 ms  23.034 ms  23.031 ms
6  be-78-rar01.chartford.ct.hartford.comcast.net (162.151.190.45)  23.097 ms be-2-ar01.needham.ma.boston.comcast.net (68.87.147.149)  19.139 ms  24.360 ms
7  be-2-ar01.needham.ma.boston.comcast.net (68.87.147.149)  25.461 ms be-32031-cs03.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.42.9)  23.414 ms be-32041-cs04.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.42.13)  28.151 ms
8  be-1311-cr11.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.35.122)  27.878 ms be-32041-cs04.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.42.13)  28.143 ms be-1111-cr11.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.35.114)  27.862 ms
9  be-302-cr22.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.38.69)  45.406 ms be-1211-cr11.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.35.118)  28.079 ms be-1111-cr11.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.35.114)  27.329 ms
10  be-302-cr22.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.38.69)  47.671 ms be-301-cr22.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.38.65)  46.801 ms be-1122-cs21.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.84.57)  45.940 ms
11  be-1421-cr21.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.82.254)  47.227 ms be-1221-cr21.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.82.246)  44.889 ms be-1122-cs21.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.84.57)  41.882 ms
12  be-1221-cr21.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.82.246)  48.081 ms be-301-cr11.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.37.146)  67.352 ms be-1221-cr21.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.82.246)  42.432 ms
13  be-304-cr11.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.37.158)  69.082 ms be-1211-cs02.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.39.69)  67.950 ms  67.547 ms
14  be-1111-cs01.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.39.65)  69.026 ms be-1214-cr14.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.39.118)  68.741 ms be-1114-cr14.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.39.114)  67.180 ms
15  be-1314-cr14.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.39.122)  64.962 ms be-304-cr14.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.39.13)  68.122 ms be-1214-cr14.1601milehigh.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.39.118)  67.736 ms
16  be-1214-cs02.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.37.245)  68.113 ms be-1414-cs04.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.37.253)  67.342 ms be-302-cr13.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.36.197)  67.724 ms
17  be-3212-pe12.910fifteenth.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.33.134)  67.742 ms be-1214-cs02.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.37.245)  68.097 ms be-1114-cs01.champa.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.37.241)  73.316 ms
18  be-3211-pe11.910fifteenth.co.ibone.comcast.net (96.110.33.118)  62.227 ms * *
19  52.93.74.61 (52.93.74.61)  76.293 ms * 52.93.74.79 (52.93.74.79)  66.094 ms
20  * * 52.93.74.141 (52.93.74.141)  68.057 ms
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  108.166.236.5 (108.166.236.5)  94.632 ms 108.166.228.47 (108.166.228.47)  93.873 ms 108.166.236.5 (108.166.236.5)  93.521 ms
28  108.166.236.19 (108.166.236.19)  93.517 ms 108.166.236.16 (108.166.236.16)  93.320 ms *
29  108.166.228.39 (108.166.228.39)  94.677 ms * *
30  108.166.228.36 (108.166.228.36)  93.261 ms * *

---

Your system still has some issues.
Please fix those and re-run this script again.

Cytoscape was installed but did not start on Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Hi Alex.  Can you provide some information on what happens when you try to start Cytoscape?  If you tried to start it by clicking on the icon, can you also try starting it by running the cytoscape.sh script in the install directory?  That will help us figure out what's going on.

Comment: Also note that Cytoscape 3.10 requires Java 17, and you have Java 11 installed.